# error creating a stacked bar chart with Google Sheets API v4 using python

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am trying to create a stacked bar chart using the Google Sheets API v4.  I have successfully created the chart without stacking (i.e. the two series in the chart are displayed side by side).  But when I try to add the option for it to be stacked, I get an error.  I am following the documentation found at https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#BasicChartSpec.

When I add the option stackedType to the passed parameters in json (with the value "STACKED"), I get the following error:

"Invalid requests[0].addChart: chartSpec.basicChart.stackedType not supported when chartSpec.basicChart.chartType is BAR."

I don't understand this error message, because the documentation says that stackedType applies to Bar charts.  Has anyone else encountered this issue?

I have my request I am sending (in json format) below:

```
chart_request = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "addChart": {
                "chart": {
                    "spec": {
                        "title": title,
                        "basicChart": {
                            "chartType": "BAR",
                            "legendPosition": "RIGHT_LEGEND",
                            "axis": [
                                {
                                    "position": "BOTTOM_AXIS",
                                    "title": "Revenue ($)"
                                    },
                                {
                                    "position": "LEFT_AXIS",
                                    "title": "Channel"
                                    }
                                ],
                            "domains": [
                                {
                                    "domain": {
                                        "sourceRange": {
                                            "sources": [
                                                {
                                                    "sheetId": sheetId,
                                                    "startRowIndex": 0,
                                                    "endRowIndex": nrows,
                                                    "startColumnIndex": 0,
                                                    "endColumnIndex": 1
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                            "series": [
                                {
                                    "series": {
                                        "sourceRange": {
                                            "sources": [
                                                {
                                                    "sheetId": sheetId,
                                                    "startRowIndex": 0,
                                                    "endRowIndex": nrows,
                                                    "startColumnIndex": 2,
                                                    "endColumnIndex": 3
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        },
                                    "targetAxis": "BOTTOM_AXIS"
                                    },
                                {
                                    "series": {
                                        "sourceRange": {
                                            "sources": [
                                                {
                                                    "sheetId": sheetId,
                                                    "startRowIndex": 0,
                                                    "endRowIndex": nrows,
                                                    "startColumnIndex": 5,
                                                    "endColumnIndex": 6
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        },
                                    "targetAxis": "BOTTOM_AXIS"
                                    }
                                ],
                            "headerCount": 1,
                            "stackedType": "STACKED",
                            }
                        },
                    "position": {
                        "overlayPosition": {
                            "anchorCell": {
                                "sheetId": sheetId,
                                "rowIndex": 15,
                                "columnIndex": 0,
                                },
                            "widthPixels": 600,
                            "heightPixels": 300,
                            },
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [BasicChartSeries](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#basicchartseries) it does say that it is only valid for chartType COMBO:

> enum(BasicChartType)
>
> **The type of this series. Valid only if the chartType is COMBO**. Different types will change the way the series is visualized. Only
>   LINE, AREA, and COLUMN are supported.

I suggest you check if what you're doing works with COMBO chartTypes. If it does, then that confirms your problem, only COMBO chart type is supported.

Answer (score 1):

I'm an engineer on the Google Sheets team.  We've found a bug when creating stacked charts via the API that will be fixed very shortly.

Thank you for posting this!

- Michael